# How can I disable Ubuntu 12.04's E-mail thing?

Tags: 12.04, boot, startup, email

I use G-Mail. I don't need Ubuntu to boot up its own E-mail program, cramming up my boot times when I try to start my system?

How can I disable the E-mail program?

Comment: Are you taking about Thunderbird? Thunderbird doesn't start automatically until you put it in startup programs.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop does not include any "email program" (client or server). Still, if you wish to save about 40-45 megabytes of space, you can remove it's default email client, Thunderbird, with:

- Open Terminal with `Ctrl+Alt+T`
- Type `sudo apt-get remove --purge thunderbird -y`
- Then type `exit`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the Messaging menu (looks like an email icon in the menu), there are several packages that need to be removed to do this (Thunderbird, Gwibber, Empathy and a few indicators). This is hard to accomplish from the command line, as there are some packages with a similar name that if removed, will also remove Ubuntu Desktop! So removing the Messaging menu is best accomplished using the Synaptic package manager. To install Synaptic, open a Terminal window (ctrl-alt-T), and enter at the command prompt:

sudo apt-get install synaptic

To open Synaptic after it is installed, enter at the command prompt:

sudo synaptic

The first thing to do is remove Gwibber (a twitter/Facebook/etc client). In the quick filter box at the top of the Synaptic screen, type 'gwibber'. Wait a few seconds, and the list of packages is updated. Any items that have a green box in front of them, click on the green box and select 'Mark for Complete Removal'. After you have done this with all the green boxes, click on the Apply button.

Handy tip: click on the S at the top of the column with the check boxes, and all the ones that are green will be sorted to the top.

Make sure in the confirmation box that none of the packages to be removed are Ubuntu Desktop. You will want check for this whenever you remove a package.

Next you want to remove Thunderbird (email app). In the quick filter box type 'thunderbird'. Do the same steps as before, click on any with a green box, and mark for complete removal. EXCEPT DO NOT REMOVE nautilus-sendto, as this will also remove Ubuntu Desktop. Click Apply and wait for it to process.

Next remove Empathy by typing empathy in the quick filter box. Mark for complete removal all items with a green box EXCEPT DO NOT REMOVE adium-theme-ubuntu, which will also remove Ubuntu Desktop. Isn't this fun? Click Apply and wait for it to process.

Last thing to do is remove the menu itself. In quick filter type 'indicator'. This time just a few items are to be removed. DO NOT check every item with a green box. Look for these four items and 'Mark for Removal' (DO NOT do complete removal, m'kay?)

indicator-messages
indicator-status-provider-mc5
libindicator-messages-status-provider1
telepathy-indicator

Click Apply and wait for it process. That's it! Log out and log in again (or restart) and the Messaging menu is gone.

source: http://jonnyholroyd.x10.mx/?p=62